# Magento 2.3.3: How to get the form_key inside a CMS page

Tags: content-management-system, magento2

I want to insert a **"To Cart"** link inside a CMS page. 
Like

```
/cart/add?product=9706&qty=1&form_key={{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::formkey.phtml"}}
```

The old way of using the singleton does not work anymore. So I've created a `formkey.phtml` inside my template directory and included it via template tag inside my CMS page. But it does not work. As I understand it, the form_key is returned by `Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey`

The template tag I am using:
`{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::formkey.phtml"}}`

formkey.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var $block Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey\ */
?>
<?= $block->getFormKey() ?>
```

But unfortunately it does nothing.

I know that if I just call:

```
{{block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey"}}
```

I get a rendered hidden field for the form_key. But I need to call the getFormKey() inside this class.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was actually very simple, if one knows how to access the function:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey" output="getFormKey"}}
```

does the trick.